# Unable to access/run executable jar placed within the project

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I am trying to run an executable jar places in the `resources` folder of my project. If I place the jar in any directory of my File System and provide the absolute path, it works fine.
Please see the code below:

```
    String jarPath = "C:\\JarFolder\\myJar.jar";        
    String command = "java -jar";
    String space = " ";
    String params = "-a abc";
    try {
        proc = Runtime
                .getRuntime()
                .exec(command + space + jarPath + space + params);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But when I place the jar inside the `resources` folder, and set the relative jar path as:

```
    String jarPath = "..\\..\\..\\resources\\myJar.jar";
```

I get an error: `Error: Unable to access jarfile ..\\..\\..\\resources\\myJar.jar`

I have verified the path, it is valid.
Am I doing something wrong here? Is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: What do you get when you call: *Runtime
                .getRuntime()
                .exec("cmd /c dir ..\\..\\..\\resources");* ?

Comment: Are you in one of windows virtual folders? User's `Documents`  or similar. They might cause problems on command line

Comment: >> Volume in drive D is New Volume


>> Volume Serial Number is 92A4-BDF7

>>

>> Directory of D:\Software\eclipse

>>

>>File Not Found`

Comment: Can you try to access it with command line?

Comment: Since (from the cmd test proposed by @agad ) it seems that you are searching the folder `D:\Software\eclipse`, please double check that you have folder `D:\Software\eclipse\resources` and it contains correct non-empty file `myJar.jar`

Comment: Relative path. So not a good idea.

Comment: it would be helpful if you can outline ur project structure or an image of it will be good

Answer (score 4):

Use the ClassLoader to get the path of your resource.

```
String jarPath = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("myJar.jar").getPath();      
String command = "java -jar";
String space = " ";
String params = "-a abc";
try {
    proc = Runtime
            .getRuntime()
            .exec(command + space + jarPath + space + params);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If this is being ran from a main static method, then just replace this.getClass() with YourClass.class.

Answer (score 0):

Relative path should work straight forward. Need more details of the error description you see and project folder structure (where the executing jar is placed and where is the import folder placed.)

Other alternate solution is to find the absolute file location of the currently executing jar file. You can fetch it with below code snippet.

```
MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath();
```

Other jar file to be executed must be placed somewhere in the same folder or in some child folders.

Now remove the current jar file name from the absolute path and append the relative path of the other jar file and execute it. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on window, you can use as follow. I have tested this code and it works.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{
        String jarPath = test.class.getClass().getResource("/resources/b.jar").getPath();      
        System.out.println("jarPath "+ jarPath);
//the result path have extra "/" so we have to remove it as follow.
        jarPath = jarPath.substring(1);
//and again the result is encoded so we need to decode it back
        jarPath = URLDecoder.decode(jarPath);
        Runtime
        .getRuntime()
        .exec("java -jar \""+jarPath+"\"");
    }

}
```

Note: I put my runnable jar in my resources folder with name "b.jar".

And the above codes need some modification to meet your needs.
Good Luck